# Unable to Submit form In struts 2 when using validations

Tags: jsp, validation, struts2, interceptor, struts2-convention-plugin

I have been facing a problem for past few hours, that whenever I use validations in my application I get empty values on server-side.

My action file seems like this:

```
@ParentPackage("interceptions")
@InterceptorRefs({  
    @InterceptorRef("loggingStack")  
})
@Results({@Result(name="login",location="login.layout",type="tiles")})
public class LoginAction extends ActionSupport implements ModelDriven{
    UpUser user = new UpUser();
    String customField;
    @Validations(requiredFields={@RequiredFieldValidator(type=ValidatorType.SIMPLE,fieldName="customField",message="YOU")})   
    @Action(value="/login",results={
            @Result(name="success",location="secure.layout",type="tiles")})
    public String execute() {
        if(user.getUserScreenName()==null)
            return "login";
        System.out.println(userBo.verifyUser(user));
        return "success";
    }
    public Object getModel(){
        return user;
    }
    @VisitorFieldValidator(message="")  
    public UpUser getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(UpUser user) {
        this.user = user;
    }
    public String getCustomField() {
        return customField;
    }
    public void setCustomField(String customField) {
        this.customField = customField;
    }

}
```

in my struts.xml I have defined my interceptor as:

```
<package name="interceptions" extends="struts-default" namespace="/">
<result-types>
  <result-type name="tiles" class="org.apache.struts2.views.tiles.TilesResult"/>
</result-types>
   <interceptors>
            <interceptor name="mylogging" 
                class="com.kiosk.lab.interceptor.LoggingInterceptor">
            </interceptor>
            <interceptor-stack name="loggingStack">
                <interceptor-ref name="mylogging" />
                <interceptor-ref name="validation">
    <param name="validateAnnotatedMethodOnly">true</param>
    <param name="excludeMethods">input,back,cancel,browse</param>
</interceptor-ref>
                  <interceptor-ref name="workflow">
                    <param name="excludeMethods">input,back,cancel,browse</param>
                </interceptor-ref>

            </interceptor-stack>
        </interceptors>

</package>
```

JSP through which I am sending the data is:

```
<s:submit cssClass="loginButton"/>
```

Now I am not sure about this problem but, I have even removed ActionSupport from my action and added and tested it in both ways but, no luck. Secondly, if I comment out interception part in my struts.xml and remove validations tag from my action then each and everything works fine. Else customField value at server side is null.

Updates:

After few answers it's in validating the values fine because all the values are going null in java and it's showing actual error message. But, still I have been facing similar issue that it's not submitting values from JSP. As, it always come null and it's keep on posting the same validation error messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add below so that the validation interceptor which is defined in defaultStack can be run

```
<interceptor-ref name="defaultStack" />
```

Comment: Debug you application with config-browser plugin and see if the validation is in the list of interceptors

Comment: Thanks @Alireza but it's still not giving me the values from jsp to java

Comment: Are you sure about workflow interceptor too? It seems there is no use of this in your code?!